# LINQ update statement using generic table and column names

Tags: linq, generics, parameters

OK, I've seen a lot of posts on creating generic LINQ statements, but these are usually based on select queries. What I need is a LINQ UPDATE statement that takes a generic parameter for the table to update and a generic parameter for the column to update.

The data model I'm working with has dozens of tables, and each table has potentially dozens of columns. What I'm really driving toward is a single Update statement that allows me to tell it at runtime which table and which column to update.

Dealing with data typing of these dynamically supplied fields will also be an issue since obviously I can't update a DateTime column with a decimal value for example.

So, can anyone point me at some code that shows a LINQ update process using generic parameters for table and column names.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify Entity Framework with DbContext but if that is what you are using, this is pretty easy.  The following code is written to work within the NerdDinner sample which can be downloaded from http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

This code locates a dinner based on the id and sets the address property to "New Value"

```
        Dinner dinner = db.Set<Dinner>().Find(id);

        var entry = db.Entry(dinner);
        entry.Property("Address").CurrentValue = "New Value";

        db.SaveChanges();
```